# Is おっすused by both men and women?

Tags: words, slang, gender

I know the term means hi or hello, but is it used by both genders? My research indicates a male usage, particularly in chats. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not common for women to use it, but it's not unheard of. It's not considered proper for a lady to use, so it sounds a bit more tomboyish and casual. Most likely the woman is also relatively close to the person(s) she is greeting on the friendship scale; or maybe just lazy.

Of course, if she was a karate student and was greeting a sensei or senpai, she would use 押忍{おっす}.

Answer (score 1):

A long long ago only men use it, but now also women does.  It is not a gentle word but frank one with which a boy always greets who is finding 7 balls flying on the cloud ;-)